# Azure mobile service and Native Android Facebook Auth

Tags: android, facebook, azure, authentication, xamarin

I use Azure mobile service and native android app. In my app service:
- I enabled app service auth
- I add facebook appId and app secret
When  I open redirect url 
(ex. https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/facebook/callback) than  I see the message:

"You have successfully signed in"

Now I need to log in to my app(Xamarin Android) with Native Facebook Sdk.As an example I use this [article](https://blog.xamarin.com/native-android-facebook-authentication-azure-app-service/). This is source code for this article on [GitHub](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/app-coffeecups/tree/facebook-auth). Authorization passes and I get FacebookAccessToken.
Now I'm trying to log in with this when in my service:

```
var token = new JObject();
token["access_token"] = Settings.FacebookAccessToken;
var user = await Client.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook, token);
```

But I get an exception:

```
 I/mono-stdout( 3982): 
 Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException:    
 You do not have permission to view this directory or page.     
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: 
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
```

Any ideas and suggestions about what is the cause of this error.
Perhaps another solution will work for my task - I will be grateful for any help.